# Получить строку из дочернего виджета

Tags: qt, c++

Есть два класса:

```
  class A: public QWidget
    {
     Q_OBJECT
     private:
        QString name;
        B obj;
     public:
        A(QWidget *parent): Widget(parent){connect(B, SIGNAL(func(...)), this, SLOT(...);}
        ~A(){}
    };

    class B: public QWidget
    {
     Q_OBJECT
     public:
        B(){}
        ~B(){}
     signals:
        void func(...);
    };
```

Как изменить строку name класса А из класса В?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В сигнале класса B (у тебя это функция func(...)) делаешь тип аргумента QString:

```
signals:
        void func(QString);
```

соответственно и в классе A делаешь слот (который и соединяешь коннектом с func) с такой же сигнатурой:

```
void A::setName(QString newName)
{
 name = newName;
}
```

любой вызов

```
emit func(QString("Вася"));
```

приведет к изменению имени связанного объекта класса A
Это я описываю со спецификой и возможностями QT, так как в тегах стоит qt, а общих сиплюплюсных возможностей - куча

Answer (score 0):

Класс B должен содержать указатель на класс A.

Comment: А как это обработать с помощью слотов/сигналов?